# A very complicated F1 visa administrative processing issue... What are my chances if I reapply?

Tags: phd, united-states, visa

Greetings from Turkey,

I got a fully funded PhD offer from Illinois Institute of Technology on last April. I applied for an F1 visa to enroll in for Fall 2016 semester. Even though I got an approval on my interview, my application status remained under administrative processing for almost six months. I had to defer my admission twice, regardless of my efforts and the university's efforts to contact the embassy several times, since they were extremely indifferent and unhelpful. At the end I got really upset and sent the embassy a veeeeery long e-mail that contained literal sentences like "I can't take this anymore", "WHAT COULD I HAVE EVER DONE TO DESERVE THIS?" and "Even if I get cancer and the only cure is in the US, I will never set foot in your country" (I wasn't drunk or high). At the end of the e-mail I requested the withdrawal of my application, which they instantly agreed to like they had been waiting for me to give up already.

My supervisor is trying very hard to help me and he is the coolest person on earth. So, I don't want to let this chance slip away. My question is, what would happen if I tried to apply at the same embassy. %100 administrative processing again? refusal for life? Should I apply for this visa at a different country with a valid excuse (I might do an internship abroad). Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on expatriates.stackexchange.com

Comment: You're not the first person to shoot himself in the foot out of frustration with the visa process.  And you won't be the last.  Do not despair.  I don't know whether a roundabout approach would be helpful.  You might be able to find out at some other forum, but maybe you should leave out some of the details before you ask.

Answer (score 7):

Visa questions are best asked in [expatriates.se](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com) but here's an abbreviated answer.

Visa application voluntary withdrawals are normally without prejudice towards future applications, however you showed a great deal of emotional immaturity in writing the letter the way you did.  This might have been noted in your file.

The only way you can know is to try again. Note that trying to game the system by applying from another country may actually result in greater scrutiny of your file than if you simply reapplied from your home country.

Returning to questions of academia. If I was your future advisor, I would certainly consider this a negative indication of your maturity and readiness to engage in a PhD program.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. You might be right. I am not proud of what I did but I don't find myself 100% guilty. I think that me having waited for 6 months patiently is mature enough. Besides, if my future supervisor disapproved of my readiness, I wouldn't be working remotely and voluntarily on one of his projects and taking his class as audit on his request. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, dear, indeed. Castigating an administrative unit on which you have practically no control as per other institutions/ombudspeople/legal recourse is pretty much the thing that parents warn their children of when they say that "there is a big book where all one's misdeeds are written into and never erased". You can apply again, but unless you are really, really lucky, you should start out with very low hopes, I am afraid.

Comment: I see. I already started applying to schools in other countries. Would this thing come up when I am applying for the visa of another country? Or will I be under some kind of probation for the rest of my life?

Comment: @HikmetEmreKaya The maturity is not measured by your patience in waiting but by realising the effects of your words and what your alternative options really are. You can get angry at a cashier who doesn't move fast enough (if you have the choice to switch line or shop), you can get angry at a driver who you may never see again. But getting angry at the guardians of the (currently) only pathway towards what you really want is possibly life-changing rashness. Note that they may have had order to discourage people to apply whom they couldn't outright reject and you gave them the key for this.

Comment: @HikmetEmreKaya I wouldn't generally worry about other countries unless you outright threatened them, in which case they may be forwarding your data. I of course do not assume you did that, but it goes without saying that doing anything like that in our times would constitute a career-limiting move if not worse.

Comment: No I didn't threaten them of course, I wasn't that out of mind. It was more like "making a scene and being a total drama queen"

Comment: I didn't indeed assume so, but it's for the benefit of other readers to reflect on consequences of communication. Email is a dangerous medium. It is fast enough to answer almost on the spot, but it is sufficiently persistent to be kept and remembered forever. I always think that any email client should have a "Send" button, but also a "I Am Really Angry" button that adds random Shakespearian or Torvaldian insults to the mail for added "oomph", but delays its sending by 24 hours. And, yes, with the option to stop it.

Comment: I am a very experienced e-mail user. When really angry, I sometimes write the e-mail I want to write without a destination address, just in case I hit "send" accidentally. I put it aside for at least 24 hours, and reread it. So far, I have never actually sent one I wrote while angry. The next day I either decide not to send it at all, or I find a better, more diplomatic, way to express myself.

Comment: Ouch, I am sorry that you have had to go through this, I'm glad you realize you were wrong but I think you might still have some work to do: I'm noticing here that you still feel like you were justified in how you reacted (you said you were not "100% guilty"). I wish you the best, but I think you made a pretty serious mistake. It's really really hard to truly admit responsibility; in this case, there really isn't anyone to apologize to directly, but you will need to find the courage to give yourself full responsibility if you want to avoid making similar mistakes in the future.

Comment: For some people, the "puppy" method works. Think of the other side as a puppy who just soiled your carpet. You may be really angry - but you still wouldn't kick the puppy (or so I hope :-)

Comment: @BryanKrause Very good point - OP needs to realise that the other side was perfectly in the position (and potentially entitled or even encouraged, we do not know what orders they got) to slow the process down. Assigning blame is not an option here (and is also in other cases better not done without serious reflection).

Comment: @CaptainEmacs of course I wouldn't, I own two cats myself.

Comment: @BryanKrause Of course I consider myself guilty but it wouldn't stop me from criticizing this process and its impact on students and employees like me. I just really thought that they weren't ever going to issue my visa

Comment: @HikmetEmreKaya A couple hours ago you wrote here that you didn't think you were 100%, and you thought you were "mature enough" for having waited 6 months before sending a rude, angry email. That's all I was referring to - if that's not really how you feel, no problem, just pointing out the discrepancies I see. And of course, not to make this more miserable for you, but just for advice for the future.

Comment: The amount of condescension in this comments box seems somewhat over-the-top. I do think a lot of people who would normally considered to be mature would at the very least least go off into a rant when they learn that they are essentially losing a good job due to the meddling of an unrelated third party. Have you never seen a developer ragequit from a programming project for lesser reasons?

Comment: (Also, frankly, I think the relevant authorities are somewhat used to this kind of anger thrown at them... Not saying that it is right, but saying that it is likely rather frequent.)